# Capturing Tab audio in browser from source, not microphone

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webapi, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to create a recorder plugin which can be integrated with any website. I know how to capture audio coming from the tab in chrome but unable to find a good solution which is browser independent. Is there a way to capture audio directly from tab? Again, I don't want to capture the audio coming from tab through microphone.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [getDisplayMedia](https://w3c.github.io/mediacapture-screen-share/#dom-mediadevices-getdisplaymedia) with audio is currently only supported in Chrome I think. And there is no other way from Web APIs alone (that is if you don't want to ask your users to setup a virtual audio loop on their computer and feed it as mic input). Maybe chrome:// API have something more though, not really in the extension side of the force.

Comment: We have an extension too. Which works fine because it is on chrome. But I think we have to settle for audio from mic for now.